# React radio button onChange event does not bind on first change of radio button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, radio-button

I am working with react js and found a weird issue on radio button `onChange` event binding. 
My page opens a popup on button click where a new component bind inside that popup. In this new component I have created 2 `radio buttons` and on change of that radio buttons I'm hide/show div. below is my code.

```
 class component1 extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showComponent: true
   };
  }
  handleChange = () => {
    this.setState({
      showComponent: !this.state.showComponent,
    });
  }
  render() {
   return(
   <div>
    <input type='radio' name='a' onChange={self.handleChange} defaultChecked/>
    <input type='radio' name='a' onChange={self.handleChange}/>
     {this.state.showComponent && (<div>Hide or show based on state change</div>)}
   </div>
  );
 }
}
```

When I open the popup for the first time it works fine. Perhaps its behavior change after submitting form and popup close. When next time I open popup without parent page refresh, on first change of radio button it does not call `handleChange` function. And from the second click it just works fine.

I think, `onSubmit` I have called `form.reset()` function on successful submission of form, which is creating problem. But i don't understand how to resolve this issue.

Comment: It's hard to say what might be wrong from the code currently in your question. It would be helpful if you could create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in e.g. [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new).

Comment: Perhaps it makes sense to make `handleChange` accept an argument, and do the toggling depending on that argument? Can't the value of radio buttons be 'indefinite' after you call 'form.reset()` I wonder?

Comment: probably the edit but `self.handleChange` and not `this.handleChange` which is arrow bound? you've not declared `self = this`

Comment: On handlechange (in sestate block) use the prevstate to get value of showcomp.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<input type='radio' name='a' onChange={this.handleChange} checked={!this.state.showComponent} />
<input type='radio' name='a' onChange={this.handleChange} checked={this.state.showComponent}/>
```

this will work find in a controlled way as opposed to reliance on event and defaultChecked

https://codesandbox.io/s/5z40rj836l

Comment: This is working fine. `DefaultChecked` was creating the problem after `form.reset()`. Thank you so much